# Multiple webkit animations

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I'm trying to run multiple webkit animations at once. Demo can [be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/ialphan/fLNyS/):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

    $('body').append('<div class="dot" style="left:100px; top:200px"></div>');


});
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background: #333;
}

.dot{
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f00 90%, #fff 10%);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 40px 0 0 40px;
    width: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;




    -webkit-animation: shrink 2.s ease-out;

    -webkit-animation: pulsate 4s infinite ease-in-out;
  }


  @-webkit-keyframes shrink{
    0%{
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;
      -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    }
    50%{
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
      }
    100%{
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;
          -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      }
  }

    @-webkit-keyframes pulsate{
      0%{
          -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;
      }
      50%{
          -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #111;
      }
    100%{ 
          -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #222;
      }
  }
```

.dot has two animations:

1. shrink
2. pulsate (hard to see but it's there)

Perhaps I need to find a good way sync them. Once shrink animation is done, pulsate. I can't run them both at once so pulsate is commented out in .dot.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't see any animation going on.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Pulsate is the current animation and it's really hard to see. Look for the shadow around (zooming might help). Thanks.

Comment: Nope, even after zooming in, I can't say a thing. My inspector tells me "invalid property value" on the animation property.

Comment: Maybe because of the `shrink 2.s ease-out`, i changed it to `shrink 2s ease-out` and it worked

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can separate multiple animations with a `,` and set a delay on the second one if needed:

```
-webkit-animation: shrink 2s ease-out, pulsate 4s 2s infinite ease-in-out;
```

`2s` in the second animation is the delay

---

Since Chrome 43 and Safari 9/9.2, the `-webkit-` prefix is only needed for Blackberry and UC (Android) browser. So the new correct syntax would be

```
animation: shrink 2s ease-out, pulsate 4s 2s infinite ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Animation shorthand is: `name duration timing delay`. So would be
`pulsate 4s ease-out 2s infinite`

Comment: Odd. this doesn't seem to work for me.  It only respects the first animation, not the 2nd one.

Comment: What browser are you (@Tyguy7 and @kwoxer) testing it on? Make sure to include all necessary vendor-prefixes, and a non-prefixed version too: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation
i'll edit my answer to include this case

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work for me, but in my case it only respect the last animation. Chrome 58.0.3029.96, win10