# SVG animation allow multiple keyframes

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm using keyframes to animate my svg.

I use a keyframe to animate multiple parts of a svg file.
Some parts need the same animation as the exciting keyframe but with an additional animation. In stead of duplicating the exciting keyframe and add the part I need is it possible to allow the `animation` element to have multiple keyframes?

Like this:

```
@keyframes scaleup {
0% {
    stroke: #009AFF;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-opacity:0;
}   
40% {
    stroke: #009AFF;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-opacity:1;

}
50%{
    stroke: #009AFF;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-opacity:0.5; 
}
75%{
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-opacity:0.5;     
}
100% {
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-opacity:1;
    stroke-width:5.012;
} 
from {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
to {
   transform: scale(1);
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
}
```

The above `@keyframe` is used by the following classes:

```
.mouth_outer_line{ 
    animation: scaleup 1s ease-in-out 1 both; animation-delay: 1.6s;    
}
```

If this animation is done I want to for-instance add something.
So I would like to create a separate `@keyframe` where I add the thing I want to add.

Can this be done?

Answer (score -1):

After some more Googeling I found this post:
[multiple webkit animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590562/multiple-webkit-animations)

Like this:
You can separate multiple animations with a `,` and set a delay on the second one if needed:

`-webkit-animation: shrink 2s ease-out, pulsate 4s 2s infinite ease-in-out;`
`2s` in the second animation is the delay

Since Chrome 43 and Safari 9/9.2, the `-webkit-` prefix is only needed for Blackberry and UC (Android) browser. So the new correct syntax would be

`animation: shrink 2s ease-out, pulsate 4s 2s infinite ease-in-out;`

I tried this and it works.
However what I don't know if this is the right way to do this> Depreciated or something?

Comment: If you want this to survive as an answer you need to summarise the contents of the link, otherwise if and when the link dies this answer won't contain any useful information.

Comment: Something like this captain?